# How to convert Html to Excel?

Tags: html, excel

I had html page with multiple datas.
I wish to print html result in excel.
My results are in a vertical line. But i want them in a horizontal way.

```html
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
    <tr height=14>
        <td width=21 align=left>
            <br>
        </td>
        <td width=354 align=left>
            <font style=font-size:8pt face="arial" color=#333333>children clothing</font>
        </td>
        <td width=98 align=right>
            <font style=font-size:8pt face="arial" color=#000000>page 1 of 86</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
    <tr height=14>
        <td width=21 align=left>
            <br>
        </td>
        <td width=477 align=left>
            <font style=font-size:8pt face="arial" color=#969696>_____________________________________________________________________________</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
    <tr height=20>
        <td width=20 align=left>
            <br>
        </td>
        <td width=478 align=left>
            <b>
                <font style=font-size:11pt face="verdana" color=#333333>zion garments</font>
            </b>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 id="qmstable">
    <tr height=16>
        <td width=20 align=left>
            <br>
        </td>
        <td width=105 align=left>
            <font style=font-size:8pt face="verdana" color=#000000>address</font>
        </td>
        <td width=373 align=left>
            <font style=font-size:9pt face="verdana" color=#000000>59-f, sbi colony, gandhinagar, tirupur 641603</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
    <tr height=16>
        <td width=20 align=left>
            <br>
        </td>
        <td width=105 align=left>
            <font style=font-size:8pt face="verdana" color=#000000>phone:</font>
        </td>
        <td width=373 align=left>
            <font style=font-size:9pt face="verdana" color=#000000>91-4212-477819</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Like this multiple data in multiple table.

Comment: Welcome to SO, unfortunately, we can't give you a straight answer without you posting the codes you tried first. There is an infinite number of ways to convert HTML to Excel.

Comment: I agree with James. When there's an html table involved, it is sometimes as easy as copy-pasting. Then you can use the copy paste-Transpose to switch the data from row-column to column-row. But you'll need to give more details as SO can't really answer your question in its current format.

Comment: Actually i want html result in Excel sheet. Just html to excel convert . I know lot of options there. But i want the result in horizontal store in excel sheet

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this manually, visit the following link and upload your html to the website and it will convert to excel format.

http://www.convertcsv.com/html-table-to-csv.htm

or

To convert an .html file, open it using Excel (File - Open) and then save it as a .xlsx file from Excel (File - Save as).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using libreoffice tags.  I just reposted my old article on how to do this at http://wjmceachran.com/2020/04/create-excel-files-from-legacy-system-with-libreoffice/